# Flutter Dismissible in AnimatedList make animation twice

Tags: flutter

I've an app with two rows in a AnimatedList and each row has a dismissible for remove item by swipe. 
I'd noticed when you swipe a row for remove it then animation run twice.

This is code:

```
  Widget _buildItem(BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
    Key k = new Key(_list[index]['item1'].toString());
    return Dismissible(
      key: k,
      background: Container(color: Colors.red),
      child:
      buildList(
        animation: animation,
        selected: _selectedItem == _list[index],
        item: _list[index],
      ),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        _remove(index);
      },);
  }

  void _remove(int index) {
    _list.removeAt(index);
  }
```

How to fix that?

Comment: would you mind provide workable code which can include directly in `main.dart`, so can have a test.